# Does windows phone8 sdk support c lua and luajit

Tags: windows-phone-8, lua, cocos2d-x, luajit

I am willing to develop wp8 games and preparing to use cocos2d-x wp8 version.
I want to use lua script as my main dev language, however I am not sure is wp8 sdk allow me to do that.
I did some google work myself, but only find some lua c# stuff.
Can any guru tell me can I use lua and its c api or even luajit on wp8 sdk.
Thanks for every tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua itself is ANSI C, so it *should* be able to run under the WP8 SDK, since it has no problem compiling using MSVC. Luajit might work also, but you'll have to try it yourself.

You'll need to obviously compile lua yourself for the WP8 platform.

Comment: There is no jit support on WinRT or WP8:http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/yy6zl/no_luajit_on_windows_8_for_arm/

Comment: @JohnnyWatt But I failed to compile lua lib in wp8 system, I looks as if lua depends on some windows api which are not supported by wp8. So, can you tell me how did you compile lua in wp8 system?

Comment: @Bloodwolf You need define LUA_ANSI.

Comment: @miaodadao Thanks, I have gotten lua compiled in wp8.